# How to display accented chars on the console window, that work for all compiler?

Tags: c, display, non-ascii-characters

I made a program that prints names of bus stations on the screen during running, and these names often contain accented characters. I did a solution that works just fine for me and also for my friend on Visual Studio '13 and '15, but my teacher who corrects the program answered that it doesn't work for him. The file `NULL` is in the folder that contains the code.
I used this:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

system("chcp 1250 > NULL");

printf("Mária Terézia körút\n");
```

My question: How can I make the program display accented chars on every compiler and os?

Comment: It's a tricky area, but `chcp` isn't a program on most Unix-based systems, so that's a non-starter for 'every compiler and os'.  You should probably clarify what you mean by 'every compiler and os'.  The simple fact of the matter is that you probably can't make it work for *every* compiler and os — there are too many archaic ones around that are still used and have no support for different code sets.  Fortunately, they're mostly not widely used in servers or desktop/laptop systems.  You'll need to know which codeset the terminal (console) uses, and ensure that the locale is correct for that.

Comment: Well, in the answer the teacher suggested me to test on Win 7/8/10, but I already did on 7 and 10 before I've sent. It would be also a solution if I could document that what have to be changed if it's nor working. On Code::Blocks it's not displaying the characters neither for me (GNU compiler), so I was thinking if he wasn't using Visual Studio, although it's used in school for exams too.

Comment: OK — that's a different interpretation of 'all compilers and o/s' from what I was expecting. (I count macOS, Linux, BSD, Solaris, AIX, HP-UX as operating systems that come under the "all compilers and o/s" heading.)  I can't help you further — I don't touch Windows except by accident or when necessary (and someone provides me with access to a Windows machine; I have no Windows machines of my own or at work).

Comment: OK, thank you anyway.

Comment: Nothing whatsoever works on *all* compilers. This particular functionality doesn't work on all standards-conforming compilers even in theory. The standard doesn't require that characters from any particular character can be correctly displayed on a console, or what exactly needs to be done to make your program work with a character set you need.

Comment: If your question is about various versions of Windows and MSVC rather than about "all OS and compilers", please [edit] the tite and/or body of the question so that there's no misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2):

There unfortunately is nothing that works on *all* compilers, but with a few `#if` blocks, we can get pretty close.  It has been reported that code like this fails on tdm-gcc.

The standard way to do this in C is to print a wide-character string with the standard library.  Unfortunately, that doesn’t work with the MSVC runtime without a bit of extra initialization.  If you do this, you cannot switch back and forth between the wide-character functions such as `wprintf()` and the narrow functions such as `printf()` in the same program.

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>

/* This has been reported not to autodetect correctly on tdm-gcc. */
#ifndef MS_STDLIB_BUGS // Allow overriding the autodetection.
#  if ( _WIN32 || _WIN64 )
#    define MS_STDLIB_BUGS 1
#  else
#    define MS_STDLIB_BUGS 0
#  endif
#endif

#if MS_STDLIB_BUGS
#  include <io.h>
#  include <fcntl.h>
#endif

void init_locale(void)
// Does magic so that wprintf() can work.
{
  // Constant for fwide().
  static const int wide_oriented = 1;

#if MS_STDLIB_BUGS
  // Windows needs a little non-standard magic.
  static const char locale_name[] = ".1200";
  _setmode( _fileno(stdout), _O_WTEXT );
#else
  // The correct locale name may vary by OS, e.g., "en_US.utf8".
  static const char locale_name[] = "";
#endif

  setlocale( LC_ALL, locale_name );
  fwide( stdout, wide_oriented );
}

int main(void)
{
  init_locale();
  wprintf(L"Mária Terézia körút\n");
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

For compatibility with all recent compilers, you have to save it as UTF-8 with a BOM.  (MSVC versions prior to VS 2017 cannot read UTF-8 without the BOM, and clang cannot read anything but UTF-8.)

In order to read the text on the console, you must set the font to a monospaced Unicode font, such as Lucida Console.

On Linux, make sure your locale environment variables are set correctly and that they match the settings of your terminal.

An alternative is to set the console to UTF-8 (On Windows, the command for this is `chcp 65001`.  On Linux, it’s `export LANG=en_US.utf8` or the appropriate equivalent from `locale -a`, and is probably set up by default.) and then `printf(u8"Mária Terézia körút\n");`.  Be warned: UTF-8 is a second-class citizen on Windows.

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer. The code is not working for me, there's 1 error: _0_WTEXT undeclared. Maybe there's a header missing?

Comment: @Urudin Perhaps you sholud be copying and pasting the code rather than trying to re-type it. There's an O there, not a 0.

Comment: I've copyed it to the compiler, only re-typed to comment :)

Comment: @Urudin Which compiler and OS?  Try running from a VS Native Tools prompt.

Comment: Windows 7 Pro, I tried both on Code::Blocks(GNU) and Visual studio. They give different errors. Code::Blocks gave the one I mentioned before, VS errors are:
LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)

LNK1120 1 unresolved external

Both found in the first line.

Comment: Well, according to Microsoft’s documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tw4k6df8%28v=vs.140%29.aspx), it should work for every version of MSVC from 2008 onwards. It works for me in the VS native tools prompt, MingW64, and clang. The `_O_WTEXT` flag should be defined in `<fcntl.h>` on Windows.

Comment: If your compiler is not correctly linking `main()`, it’s misconfigured. Can it compile `"hello, world!"`?  Are you compiling this as a console app?

Answer (score 0):

For compatibility with the web (W3C, IETF) and *nix systems (Linux; BSD, Android, OSX, GCC, CLang) use UTF-8 without BOM (as it was designed).

For compatibility with legacy proprietary systems that are still struggling with their unicode migration use UT-8 with BOM. Or admit they're not ready for unicode and use a legacy proprietary 8bit encoding (you *will* need to migrate to UTF-8 someday so that's just adding code needing fixing to the pile).

Hint: with BOM UTF-8 is not ASCII-compatible, killing any easy migration from 8bit encodings to Unicode.

Answer (score -1):

I managed to work out a simple solution that seems to do the trick. Using this makes the accented chars of the Hungarian language working on both Win7 and Win10 and on VS '13 '15 and Code::Blocks.

```
#include <locale.h>
#if defined(WIN32) || defined(_WIN32)
#include <windows.h>
#endif
```

In main:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
#if defined(WIN32) || defined(_WIN32)
SetConsoleCP(1250); SetConsoleOutputCP(1250);
#endif
```

Comment: 1250 is an obsolete one-byte character set which almost nobody uses, and nobody should ever use in 2017. It may or may not take care of your needs in the short run, but if you want to stay relevant in the long run you want to learn stuff about Unicode. [Here](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) is a good start. As a public answer to public question, this should be downvoted because it provides unsuspecting newbies with an extremely bad advice.

Comment: Well, it's sure this is not a complete solution for the question, Solved my problem, and working on Vstudio and Code::Blocks with Hungarian letters. I've asked my friends to test it, worked fine on 5 Windows PC, so I wrote in the description that where it was working. But I forgot to add, that I've only tested for Hungarian letters, I correct that mistake now.

Comment: This also doesn’t work on any OS other than Windows, whereas the solution with `wprintf()` and wide strings *theoretically* works on any compiler that complies with the standard.